# Unlocking a lock from a thread which doesn't own it, or redesigning to avoid this?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, stream

I have an archive object which manages various byte arrays and hands out [`InputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)s and [`OutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)s for reading and writing them. Each byte array has an associated [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

The constructor of the subclass of `InputStream` which the archive produces acquires the lock for the relevant data, while `close()` releases the lock. Now, the problem:

Suppose that I have a task which will run on another thread which needs input from the archive, is given the `InputStream` as an argument before it starts, and is responsible for closing the stream when it's finished. These requirements appear to be incompatible with the locking mechanism used by my data archive, because

1. The `InputStream` is created on a different thread from the one on which it is closed.
2. A `ReentrantReadWriteLock` must be released by the thread which owns it.

Rewriting the parts of the program which expect an `InputStream` as input in order to avoid #1 is inconvenient and makes those parts less flexible. Using a kind of lock which permits change of ownership would let me avoid #2, but I don't see any locks in the Java API which can handle that and I'm not terribly keen on knocking together a custom lock if  I don't have to.

What solutions are there to this problem?

Comment: How is your manager creating these on a different thread? That is, there is likely a method such as `getStream(<some-parameters)` of some kind in the manager class. The threads using this stream would be calling that method would they not - and that's when you can do the locking. Or are you passing these objects on to subsequent threads or trying to pool the `InputStream`s within your manager?

Comment: @Kevin: The methods which create the InputStream-using tasks are run on the same thread where the locks are acquired, but the tasks themselves are sent off to an ExecutorService. However, the task factory methods might also be called with streams which don't come from my data archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is to give the clients something other than a subclass of `InputStream`, even if this means slightly more refactoring. In your current design, you can't count on your clients releasing the lock, what if one of them does not? This is not good encapsulation.

**Have the archive object manage the locks, and provide an easy API for your clients to get the data**. Even if this means changing some APIs.

The problem of different threads locking and releasing the same object is a clear sign that you got something slightly wrong in your current design. Work on the refactoring aforementioned, it will do you a great deal further on.

Comment: I'm not worried about streams not being closed. The archive is wholly internal, not part of an outward-facing API. The number of places we create these streams is relatively small, and they're always closed inside finally blocks---but those places might be on a thread other than the one where the stream was created, and hence different from where the lock was acquired.

Comment: Well, you still have a motivation as to why you should handle the locking in the archive object... I doubt there is a cleaner way to achieve this.

Comment: Reluctantly, this is the solution I implemented. I still feel that the most elegant and straightforward way to handle this would be to have a reentrant lock for which the owner may be set to null, which would indicate that any thread may release it. Unfortunately, the method for setting the lock owner is buried in a private inner class of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your response to my question. You could simply postpone construction (and locking) of the `InputStream` by passing a custom class used to manufacture the `InputStream` to the `ThreadExecutorService`. Then the thread in the service requests the `InputStream` from this object which first constructs it (since it doesn't exist) and then you're all set.

For instance:

```
public interface InputStreamMaker {
    public InputStream getOrCreateInputStream();
}
```

Then in your main class that starts everything:

```
static class InputStreamMakerImpl implements InputStreamMaker {
    private final Manager manager; // Your manager class (or use a normal Inner class on manager)
    private InputStream is;

    // other variables needed to define how to create input stream for the particular task here

    InputStreamMakerImpl(Manager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public InputStream getOrCreateInputStream() {
         if (is == null) {
             // pass this object - so manager will have all the details to create the right stream
             is = manager.createNewStream(this);
         }

         return is;
    }
}
```

and then on the main thread...

```
...some method...
InputStreamMakerImpl maker = new InputStreamMakerImpl(manager /* or this */);
// set values needed in maker for your manager class to create the right input stream
// start the worker and pass the InputStreamMaker (maker) as the parameter instead of the InputStream
```

This inner class can have additional information as necessary to create the right stream for the worker. Now the `InputStream` is created/opened on the right thread and that thread also can close it and unlock the lock.

**Edit**: On rereading your question I see that you may not want to change any of the Worker objects that already take an `InputStream`. Then you can still do this by:

1. Creating a custom sub-class of `InputStream` that holds all the values of what I define above as `InputStreamMakerImpl`.
2. The custom `InputStream` has an internal method `getInputStream()` which does what I define for `getOrCreateInputStream()` above.
3. Then all the methods for `InputStream` simply delegate the calls, for example:

   ```
   public int read() throws IOException {
       return getInputStream().read();
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem I see here is that once you've used a stream on some thread, then that thread owns it.

Answer (score 1):

`java.io.InputStream` has total nine methods. You have already overridden one i.e. `close()` method.

I would recommend you to have lazy locking, i.e. don't aggressively acquire lock in constructor. For this make `ReentrantReadWriteLock` available in your `InputStream` sub class and have a private method  called `doAcquireLock()` that attempts to acquire the lock. Then override all the other eight methods of `InputStream` such that in all the overridden methods first make a call to `doAcquireLock()` and then delegate the operation to super.

example:

```
public int read() 
    doAcquireLock(); // This method get's the lock
    return super.read();
}
```

With this lock will be acquired by the thread that first calls any of the above eight methods and will be responsible to close as well.

Just to make sure you don't end up in deadlock situation you need to look out is to make sure client makes call to close method at the end so as to release the lock. Also none of the methods should be called after close method is called by having a boolean indicator to know if stream is already closed (stale).

Comment: What happens if client thread does not invoke close? You really got to be careful about that.

Comment: If your client thread doesn't call close(), it's just broken. What if your client thread dereferences a null, or calls System.exit()?

Comment: Calling close() is client responsibility. If client has acquired resource then it is client's responsibility to release it. System.exit()? You whole program closes so no locks at all.

Comment: You may want to use some ideas from JDBC connection pooling for returning unused streams back. http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm#CFHHCICE

Comment: This looks like a reasonable solution to me, so long as checking whether we have the lock is cheap enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution#2:**

If you don't need to keep holding on to lock until end of thread, you can implement your custom `InputStream` as below which you can give to your clients. Now whenever any thread needs to read, it will acquire lock, then read and finally automatically relinquish the lock as soon as read is complete. Your custom `OutputStream` should be similarly implemented with write lock.

.

```
public class LockingInputStream extends InputStream {
    private final InputStream byteArrayInputStream;
    private final Lock r;

    public LockingInputStream(
                    InputStream byteArrayInputStream, 
                    ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl) {
        this.byteArrayInputStream = byteArrayInputStream;
        this.r = rwl.readLock();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        r.lock();
        try {
            return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        } finally { r.unlock(); }
    }
    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        r.lock();
        try {
            return byteArrayInputStream.available();
        } finally { r.unlock(); }
    }
    ....
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        r.lock();
        try {
            byteArrayInputStream.close();
        } finally { r.unlock(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: The downside of this is that another thread could get between two of your reads and modify the data you're reading.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I stumbled upon while mulling this over: One way of viewing the problem is that it's caused by the reentrancy of the locks. `ReentrantReadWriteLock` keeps track of lock ownership in order to handle reentrancy. If I want to acquire locks on stream creation and release locks on stream closure, and close streams on threads other than the ones which on which they were created, then a reentrant lock won't work because the wrong thread will own the stream lock.

One way around this is to use a counting lock, but force all the locking outwards. First, counting lock: States are integers -1,0,1,...., where -1 means writing, 0 means unlocked, and positive n count the number of concurrent reads. This way, writes are still exclusive, but locks aren't thread specific. Forcing all locking outwards: We have methods like `exists()` where we need to acquire a read lock, but `exists()` is called by some methods which will already have a write lock. So, we split out the guts of `exists()` into a protected `existsImpl()`, which should be called only when a lock is already held (that is, internally, by other `*Impl()` methods. This way, once a lock is acquired, only the nonlocking Impl methods are called, and we avoid the need for reentrancy.

This is all well and good, except that it ends up being wickedly complex to ensure that you're not screwing up in implementing it---calling a public locked method when you should be calling a protected non-locked one---and thereby creating a deadlock. Secondly, forcing all of your locks to the outside means that you're holding onto the locks longer, so this is (probably) not good for concurrency.

So, this is something I tried, but decided against using.